# How to change vsix default installation location

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm developing a Visual Studio extensibility project using VSIX. By default, the VSIX file will install the assemblies in one of the following folders:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp\Extensions\Microsoft\<GPName>
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Microsoft p&p\<GPName>
```

Is it possible to change the output location?

Comment: I hate to be one of those people (just kidding, no I don't), but why would you want to change the location?

Comment: I need to load my assemblies using reflection because package assemblies must be strong signed and I cannot reference my assemblies that are not signed as a reference. So when the package is auto-deployed, references assemblies (reflected) and configuration files are not deployed.

Comment: So why not sign them? Or deploy your dependencies into the same directory? It's the local user folder, so you should always have sufficient privileges to write there.

Answer (score 5):

You can always easily find your own assemblies:

- you instantly get the correct path by `typeof(MyPackage).Assembly.Location` and calculate paths to other assemblies bundled within your package. But, I think this will not work if the package was registered into GAC
- you may use `myPackage.UserLocalDataPath` the VS will return you the correct (blah)/Extensions directory, located somewhere in (youruser)-(appdatalocal) folder, and then you may scan deeper into your folders and folders of other packages

It may sound like a lot of work - but it isn't; couple of lines, x-teen at most.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.  The VSIX installer chooses where to place your assemblies and the VSIX has no input into this process